# htm vertical css scroll layout

Tags: html, css

I have two div content, but it turns out that when I scroll, one div is overlaid on top of the other, how do I stop this from happening to me?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 90px 20px 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f7f6f3;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 992px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 90px;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 40px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-menu-item {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: max-content;
}

.nav-menu-link {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav-menu-link:hover,
.nav-menu-link_active {
  background-color: #fff200;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-toggle {
  color: white;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}


/* scc del slider */

.contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.slider-contenedor {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative
}

.contenido-slider {
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.contenido-slider:nth-child(1) {
  background: #332863;
}

.contenido-slider:nth-child(3) {
  background: #611a68;
}

.contenido-slider>img {
  width: 400px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
  .header {
    height: 60px;
  }
  .logo {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 60px;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #2c3e50;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    left: 100%;
    transition: left 0.3s;
  }
  .nav-menu-item {
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .nav-menu-link:hover,
  .nav-menu-link_active {
    background: none;
    color: #83c5f7;
  }
  .nav-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-menu_visible {
    left: 0;
  }
  .contenedor_oculta {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-toggle:focus:not(:focus-visible) {
    outline: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
  .contenido-slider>img {
    width: 250px;
  }
  .contenido-slider>div {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .contenido-slider h2 {
    font-size: 23px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .contenido-slider {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .contenido-slider>div {
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e5b2d153f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="header">

  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="#" class="logo nav-link">
      <img src="Img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="responsive">
    </a>
    <button class="nav-toggle" aria-label="Abrir menú">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li class="nav-menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Videos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Sobre mí</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-menu-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link nav-menu-link_active">Contacto</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
      <h1>Responsive Navbar</h1>
      <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="slider-contenedor">
            <section class="contenido-slider">
              
                <img src="Img/banner.jpeg" alt="">
  
            </section>
            <section class="contenido-slider">
              
                <img src="Img/taller1.jpeg" alt="">
  
            </section>
        <section class="contenido-slider">
            <div>
             
            <img src="Img/animacion3.svg" alt="">
  
        </section>
        <section class="contenido-slider">
          
            <img src="Img/banner.jpeg" alt="">
  
        </section>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="slider-contenedor">
          <section class="contenido-slider">
            
              <img src="Img/banner.jpeg" alt="">

          </section>
          <section class="contenido-slider">
            
              <img src="Img/taller1.jpeg" alt="">

          </section>
      <section class="contenido-slider">
          <div>
           
          <img src="Img/animacion3.svg" alt="">

      </section>
      <section class="contenido-slider">
        
          <img src="Img/banner.jpeg" alt="">

      </section>
  </div>
  </div>
    </main>
```

this is the result when you load the page, apparently it loads normal

[image: html page]

when I scroll down it closes the nav menu

[image: html scroll]

Comment: With your given code the two purple divs aren't overlapping each other but the nav is. Could you mean the nav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT (as per Ghunter's comment):

Changing the header element's z-index to anything above 0 does the trick.

*OLD anwser:*

*Its a stacking issue. You have .navbar as z-index: 0;
The .contendor div is relative and doesnt have a z-index defined. So the logic is that is stacked on top of the .navbar
Set .navbar to z-index: 99; to ensure its always on top.**

Comment: This is wrong, there is no `.navbar` in his css, so I'm assuming that's a typo and it refers to `.nav` as it has the property-value `z-index: 0`, changing that wouldn't fix the issue as the nav element is nested in header which has `position: fixed`, because header is positioned it creates another stacking context layer, so changing the `.nav` z-index would [only put it above its siblings](https://jsfiddle.net/Gunterberg/j692mxqn/) (but it has no siblings). The correct (using the same approach as this is not the only solution) is to change the `.header` z-index to a value higher than 0.

Comment: It must have been a typo/ naming convention assumption, my bad
Either way, you are right. Changing the z-index of the header element does the trick.

Comment: Glad I could help, your original anwer was good enough to help the author, that's what matters, I was just improving it to be more precise for anyone that might see this in the future.